# Configuration of infinitely near points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Despite the fact that Hartshorne (in *Algebraic Geometry*, Ch. 5, Exercise 3.8) asserts that the singularities of the plane curves

$$x^4-xy^4=0$$
and
$$x^4-x^2y^3-x^2y^5+y^8=0,$$
have "the same configuration of infinitely near singular points with the same multiplicities", it seems to me that after a single blowup the new first curve possesses a single singular point of multiplicity $2$, while the new second curve possesses a single singular point of multiplicity $3$; who (if anyone) is correct?

Comment: It appears to me that after one blowup, the proper transforms of both curves have a singular point of multiplicity 3.

Comment: For example, to get the blowup of the first curve (in one of the charts), I made the substitution $(x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)$, yielding the equation $x^4y^4-xy^5$; the proper transform has equation $x^4-xy$. The singular point $(0,0)$ has multiplicity $2$.

Comment: You are right; I made an error in my calculation.