# Calculating infinitely near points of a curve singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra-systems, singularity-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with a singular point at the origin $(0,0)$. Currently I am writing a Maple program to compute its iterated blow-up embedded resolution as a hierarchy of charts which are linked by coordinate transformations of the type $[x = x, y = t x]$ and $[x = s y, y = y]$. It works quite straightforward, the greatest difficulty was the bookkeeping and to find a proper order for recursion. See the bottom of the page

http://www.aviduratas.de/compalg.html

for the current version and an example use.

The resolution graphs that I compute from this tree seem to come out right now, but I have problems with computing the (numbers and multiplicites of) infinitely near points of $(0,0)$, that is the points of the transform of $f = 0$ that lie above $(0,0)$ in the collection of charts generated.

For debugging it would be useful to have a computer algebra system that can calculate the (multiplicities of) infinitely near points, or at least to have a list of known correct examples.

At first I thought that for example the Singular system should have such functionality but I could not find it in the manual.

Does anyone know of a software for calculating the infinitely near points that is publicly available on the internet? Maybe someone who wrote for his own use such a routine?

(I came to write this program to solve Hartshorne V, ex. 3.8. While researching the above question I noted the following post:

[Configuration of infinitely near points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867504/configuration-of-infinitely-near-points)

My own calculations support the view of the OP there that there is a mistake in the exercise, does anyone know more here?)